# Solving supertype-subtype relationship without sacrificing data consistency in a relational database

Tags: database-design, subtypes, consistency

Trying to get better at designing databases, I noticed I'm always stuck trying to solve variations of the exact same problem.

Here is an example using common requirements:

1. An online store sells different categories of `product`.
2. The system must be able to retrieve the list of all product categories, say `food` and `furniture`.
3. A customer may order any product and retrieve his `order` history.
4. System must store specific properties depending on the product category ; say the `expiration_date` and `calories` for any `food` product and `manufacture_date` for any `furniture` product.

If it wasn't for requirement 4, the model could be quite straightforward:

[image]

Problem is trying to solve requirement 4. I thought of something like this:

[image]

In this approach, the relationships `product-furniture` and `product-food` are *supertype-subtype* (or superclass-subclass) associations; the primary key of the subtype is also a foreign key to the supertype primary key.

However, this approach can not guarantee the `category` referenced via a foreign key to the `product` will be consistent with its actual subtype. For instance, nothing stops me from setting `food` category to a product tuple having a subtype row in the `Furniture` table.

I read various articles about inheritance in modelling relational databases, especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190296/how-do-you-effectively-model-inheritance-in-a-database) and [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/184117/database-relationship-inheritance) which were very helpful but didn't solve my problem for the reason mentioned above. But whatever model I come with, I'm never satisfied with the data consistency.

How can I solve requirement 4 without sacrificing data consistency ? Am I going all wrong here ? If so, what would be the best way to solve this problem based on these requirements ?

Comment: You are not alone. There are hundreds of questions in this area that are asking for exactly the same help, except for the specifics of the case.  You are the exception in recognizing the similarity of all your cases.  An additional answer is listed [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193394/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-have-several-mutually-exclusive-one-to-one-relationships/193401#193401).  This covers much of the same ground as the answers you've highlighted,  but perhaps adds something with the buzzwords "single table inheritance"  and "class table inheritance".

Comment: If you want to read an in depth treatment of that same subject,  I recommend you read something by Martin Fowler.  You can get started [here](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html).

Answer (score 2):

One common way is to add a classifier that is "inherited" like:

```
CREATE TABLE products
( product_id ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, ...
, product_type ... NOT NULL 
,     UNIQUE (product_id, products_type)
,     CHECK (product_type IN ('food', 'furniture'))
);
```

product_type would typically be a code of some kind. Might be a foreign key to a "lookup" table instead of a check constraint. For the sub-types:

```
CREATE TABLE food
( product_id ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, ...
, product_type ... DEFAULT 'food' NOT NULL
,    FOREIGN KEY (product_id, product_type)
     REFERENCES products (product_id, product_type)
,    CHECK (product_type = 'food')
);
```

and a similar one for furniture. The constraints guarantee that product_type is consistent between super- an sub- tables.

There are products (I've heard) that allow sub-selects in CHECK constraints, but the majority do not. For such product something like:

```
CREATE TABLE food
( product_id ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, ...
,    FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
     REFERENCES products (product_id)
,    CHECK (
         (SELECT product_type 
          FROM products p 
          WHERE p.product_id = product_id) = 'food'
     )
);
```

could be used.

An alternative to the latter is to use before triggers for insert/update, and signal an exception if the wrong product_type is used. Personally I don't fancy using procedural code for integrity constraints, but I guess it is a matter of taste.

EDIT: If you for one reason or another want to abandon check constraints    (personally I don't find them problematic) you can easily replace them with:

```
CREATE TABLE food_types
( food_type text not null );

INSERT INTO food_types (food_type) VALUES ('food);
```

Now you can add a foreign key constraint instead of the check constraint like:

```
CREATE TABLE food
( product_id ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, ...
, product_type ... DEFAULT 'food' NOT NULL
,    FOREIGN KEY (product_id, product_type)
     REFERENCES products (product_id, product_type)

,    FOREIGN KEY (product_type)
     REFERENCES food_types (food_type) 
);
```

Comment: yeah, IMO it is bad design if we need procedural code for integrity constraints. Can you suggest other database design solution?

Comment: The first part of my answer (down to "An alternative ..." contains no procedural code.

Comment: **Before trigger** and also **check constraints**, I think it is same logical procedural code. What I mean is database design without using any code, just integrity constraints from table. Is that possible?

Comment: You can replace the check constraint with a foreign key against a domain table.

Comment: Can you please elaborate *foreign key against a domain table* in your answer?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I think that only handle the inconsistency of supertype and subtype, the questioner mentions that *However, this approach can not guarantee the category referenced via a foreign key to the product will be consistent with its actual subtype.*. What do you think?

Comment: I dont follow, can you give an example in a db<>fiddle?

Comment: @user174739 already mentioned it, *For instance, nothing stops me from setting food category to a product tuple having a subtype row in the Furniture table.* It also frustating me, #1 I think it is wrong database design or #2 good database design but need logical procedural code.

Comment: Either you don't understand my answer or I don't understand your objection. I created a fiddle for you https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a95be50ca3e7bb76a2cafbe7dccc48e0, can you enlighten me on what the problem with that is?

Comment: I already give you some cases so we can understand better at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6c8c3909628bb9b607dab31e2b5bfc47

Comment: You need to "inherit" category to the level where you want to enforce it

Comment: It is like **FOREIGN KEY (product_id, product_type)**?

Comment: And also **product_type** inside food & furniture table will duplicate many-many times, is that pass 3nf?

Comment: I have modified your fiddle at: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=18afd7ca5824a05950bae314dbe348c0  Your category_id replaces the product_type in my fiddle

Comment: Thank you, I just realized, that I just need to inherit categories.id to subtype.
Maybe you should update your answer, and hope the questioner accept it.

Comment: Somehow I doubt that a two year old question all the sudden will be accepted

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm simplifying the requirement, but to satisfy the requirement and your concern is to simply set the required columns in the subtype to NOT NULL.  When a new PRODUCT row of food is created, a new FOOD row will also be created, and if no info is provided required for FOOD, then the database will reject the transaction.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think a database should be responsible for stopping someone from misclassifying the sub-type of a record. That seems much more like a business logic layer problem. So, I don't see too big of a problem with your second scenario. I've seen it work pretty well in even very large enterprise solutions.

At large table size (like 2 million or more), the JOIN query that will be necessary to combine sub-class and super-class is going to have trouble scaling with ad-hoc queries if you need to join more than a few thousand results between the two tables. For that reason a Table-per-hierarchy model might be better - the object inheritance is flattened into a single physical table.

I do wonder about what would be the best way to handle the case of re-classifying a product in your example. Any sub-type record that was previously created would need to be deleted since only one sub-type should exist for each super-type record - assuming only a single layer of inheritance. Should that be a database trigger or something handled in the Business Logic Layer?